# Is C is basis of vector space V

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ are basis of vector space $V$ over $\Bbb{R}$ then is
$C=\{ 2e_1, 3e_{1}+e_{3}, 6e_{1}+3e_{2}+e_{3} \} $ a basis of $V$?
Can anyone help ? 
$C$ can be reduce to trivial basis given by some column operation so I think it must be basis .
But my textbook says its not!!

Answer (score 2):

The equation
\begin{align}
x_1(2e_1)+x_2(3e_1+e_3)+x_3(6e_1+3e_2+e_3)=0
\end{align}
is equivalent to
\begin{align}
(2x_1+3x_2+6x_3)e_1+3x_3e_2+(x_2+x_3)e_3=0
\end{align}
Now $e_1,e_2,e_3$forms a basis, thus we have
\begin{align}
2x_1+3x_3+6x_3&=0\\
3x_3&=0\\
x_2+x_3&=0
\end{align}
This implies the family $C$ is linear independent, hence a basis.

Answer (score 1):

It is basis because
$$e_1=\frac12(2e_1)\\e_2=\frac{(6e_1+3e_2+e_3)-(3e_1+e_3)-\frac32(2e_1)}{3} \\e_3=(3e_1+e_3)-\frac32(2e_1)$$

so $C$ spans the basis and consequently the whole space $V$.

And if the dimension of a vector space is $n$ and set of  $n$ vectors spans $V$, then that set is basis.

Answer (score -1):

Hint :

- You can write the matrix of passage from $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ to C. Your problem is then: is that matrix invertible ?
- I think you're right. Can you show us exactly how the result is given in your textbook ?

Comment: not given here e1,e2,e3 are basis elements. Should I have to make C by linear combination of $e_{i}$

Comment: C is already given as a linear combination of $e_i$. You can either write $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ as a combination of the elements of C (that seems to be what you have done), of calculate a determinant.

Comment: If C span $e_{i}$ imply C span V is this u r trying to say ?

Comment: Correct. Can you reconciliate that with your textbook ?